# Area 51 Discuss Link Goes to Old Chat Parent

Tags: bug, chat, area-51, top-bar, navigation

If you go to [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) and click on the "chat" link, it redirects to a list of rooms that seems to be parented to `discuss.area51.stackexchange.com`, while the parent site that is used for new Area 51 chatrooms is `area51.meta.stackexchange.com`. This seems like it should be changed to go to the right chat parent.

[image]